# Should a wife of permanent deacon candidate be a Catholic?

Tags: catholicism, deacons

Should a wife of permanent deacon candidate be a Catholic?

Can she belong to some schismatic (non-Catholic) church, like Eastern Orthodox, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [St. Joseph Foumdation](http://stjosephcanonlaw.com/) posting on EWTN forums, there is no universal rule.

> There is no requirement in the universal Church that a deacon's wife be baptized.
> [St. Joseph Foundation via EWTN forums](http://www.ewtn.com/v/experts/showmessage.asp?number=348523&Pg=&Pgnu=&recnu=)

But like many other rules concerning the permenant diaconate, the family commitment to the deacons ordination process is up to the diocesan bishop.  Furthermore, a wife must be give her consent that her husband become a deacon.

> A candidate for the permanent diaconate who is not married may be admitted to the diaconate only when he has completed at least his twenty-fifth year; if he is married, not until he has completed at least his thirty-fifth year, and then with the consent of his wife.
>
> Can. 1031 §2

So, presumably, the wife is not going to be a dyed in the wool devil worshipper.